# How to create custom function on OData RESTier

Tags: asp.net-mvc, odata, restier

I'm referring to http://odata.github.io/RESTier/#03-01-Operations on how to create a custom method that takes in input and return a list of object.

Here's my custom method

```
[HttpGet]
[ODataRoute("Locations/PointLoc.Data.GetLocationsByMarketId()")]
public IHttpActionResult GetLocationsByMarketId()
{
    var database = new Database();
    var locations = database.Locations.GetAllLocationsByMarket(1);
    return Ok(locations);
}
```

And here's how I set it in my DbDomain

```
protected EdmModel OnModelExtending(EdmModel model)
{
    var ns = model.DeclaredNamespaces.First();

    var location = model.FindDeclaredType(ns + "." + "Location");
    var locations = EdmCoreModel.GetCollection(location.GetEdmTypeReference(isNullable: false));

    var getLocationsWithMarketId = new EdmFunction(ns, "GetLocationsWithMarketId", locations, true, null, false);
    getLocationsWithMarketId.AddParameter("bindingParameter", locations);
    model.AddElement(getLocationsWithMarketId);

    return model;
}
```

Can't get it to work. Keep getting OData Uri error like

*'Locations/PointLoc.Data.GetLocationsByMarketId()' on the action 'GetLocationsByMarketId' in controller 'PointLoc' is not a valid OData path template. The request URI is not valid. Since the segment 'Locations' refers to a collection, this must be the last segment in the request URI or it must be followed by an function or action that can be bound to it otherwise all intermediate segments must refer to a single resource.*

**Wanted to access the Odata via "/Locations/GetLocationsByMarketId". How to do it?**

Comment: You don't need to add the parenthesis after GetLocationsByMarketId in the ODataRoute. In addition, if you still have problems with that, please post the part of that function in the $metadata.

Comment: @LewisCheng-MSFT thanks. Manage to get it to work but I can't seems to get to return a list of the result. Here's the problem - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31758820/restier-odata-function-returning-entityset-the-related-entity-set-could-not-be

Comment: @LewisCheng-MSFT will delete this question in few days time as I think this is not question is not relevant I can't post the answer until i solve the problem in my previous comment.

Comment: A precise guide on creating function on RESTier is given by @LewisCheng-MSFT on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31758820/restier-odata-function-returning-entityset-the-related-entity-set-could-not-be